# React component re renders to it's initial state automatically

Tags: reactjs

I am making a simple react test application.

**What is the application**: It shows names of projects and has an option to add a new project. Each project has title and category.

This is how it looks

[image]

**Problem:** When I try to add a new project by entering the title and then clicking on submit button, the new project name appears in the projects for a fraction of seconds and then disappears. The project list gets back to the initial state which is three projects (which are shown below)

This is the code

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';
import Projects from "./Components/Projects"
import AddProjects from './Components/AddProject'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      projects:[]
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
      this.setState({projects:[
          {
              title: "Trigger",
              category: "Web App"
          },
          {
              title: "Trigger",
              category: "Web App"
          },
          {
              title: "Trigger",
              category: "Web App"
          }
      ]})
  }

  handleAddProject(project){
      let projects = this.state.projects;
      projects.push(project)
      this.setState({projects:projects})
      console.log(this.state.projects)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        My Project
          <AddProjects addProject={this.handleAddProject.bind(this)}/>
          <Projects projects={this.state.projects}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Projects.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Projectitem from './ProjectItem'


class Projects extends Component {

    render() {
        let projectItems
        if(this.props.projects){
            projectItems = this.props.projects.map(project =>{
                return (
                    <Projectitem project={project}/>
                );
            })
        }
        else{
            console.log("hello")
        }

        return (
            <div>
                This is a list of objects
                {projectItems}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Projects
```

ProjectItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class ProjectItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

                <li>
                    {this.props.project.title}:{this.props.project.category}
                </li>

        );
    }
}

export default ProjectItem
```

AddProject.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


var categories = ["Web dev", "Mobile dev", "websiite"]

class AddProject extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            newProject:{}
        }
    }


    handleSubmit(){
        this.setState({newProject:{
            title:this.refs.title.value,
            category:this.refs.category.value
        }}, function () {
            this.props.addProject(this.state.newProject)
        })
    }
    render() {
        var categoryOptions = categories.map(category=>{
            return <option key={category} value={category}>{category}</option>
        })
        return (
            <div>
                Add Project <br/>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <div>
                        <label>title</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" ref="title"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Category</label><br/>
                        <select ref="category">
                            {categoryOptions}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default AddProject
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `event.preventDefault()` to your `handleSubmit()` method

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
}
```

Without it your page will refresh (as it does by default when a form is submitted)

Comment: Perfect. Rooky Mistake. Thanks

Comment: No problem. If you could accept the answer that would be great! :)

Comment: @ApurvG did this solve your problem? Seen my answer?

Answer (score 3):

You are editting the state directly, that's a big no-no in React.

Change your handler function to something like this:

```
handleAddProject(project){
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return { projects: [...prevState.projects, project] }
  })
}
```

The `setState` function can be called using a 'callback', that receives the state previous to its call, and lets you modify it. The important part is **not** mutating the state directly (as your `projects.push(project)` line is doing).

Other option, that's more like what you are already trying to do, is copying the current state before mutating it:

```
handleAddProject(project){
  let projects = this.state.projects.slice(); // notice the slice here will return
                                              // a copy of 'projects', and then
                                              // you modify it
  projects.push(project)
  this.setState({projects:projects})
  console.log(this.state.projects)
}
```

Also, keep in mind, `setState` is called *asynchronously*, so the `console.log(this.state.projects)` call may show the old state yet, as `setState` may not have been called yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [Form tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) which is for submit information to a web server if you use the input type="submit" it will always reload the page and initial everithig as the first time loaded. If you do as @Galupuf it will work 
 because the event.preventDefault(); will not allow the browser to reload and it will not initial everyting as first time loaded.

My answer is if you are not sending any data to any sever or working with a server at all change the form tag for div the input type="submit" for`<button onClick={()=>this.handleSubmit()}>Send</button>`

```
 <div>
                <div>
                    <label>title</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" ref="title"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Category</label><br/>
                    <select ref="category">
                        {categoryOptions}
                    </select>
                </div>
                  <button onClick={()=>this.handleSubmit()}>Submit</button>
            </div>
```

other suggestion work the modified value of the state like @cfraser suggest like that you will have immutable data